# Find max element and its key in Object - React native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I First must tell that i browsed the site here to find an answer but i couldn't.

I have an object which holds a key(service Name) and a value(counter), i want to extract from this object only the Max and Min value, and their keys.

an example:

```
Object {
  "Learn JavaScript": 3, //Max
  "Learn React": 2, //Ignore
  "manicure": 1, //Min
}
```

and then i would like to create an array of objects which will hold them in desecending order

code i used to display the upper outcome:

```
 const arrayofServices  = services; //services => state the holding the services
          const servicesCounter = arrayofServices.reduce((counterObj, service) => {
            if (counterObj.hasOwnProperty(service)) {
              counterObj[service] += 1;
              return counterObj;
          }
          
            return {
              ...counterObj,
              [service]: 1
            };
          }, {});
          console.log("Service Counter in =>" ,servicesCounter);
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more try  :)

```js
const obj = {"Learn JavaScript": 3, "Learn React": 2, "manicure": 1};

function MinMaxFromObj(obj) {
  const min = Math.min(...Object.values(obj));
  const max = Math.max(...Object.values(obj));
  const minKey = Object.entries(obj).find(([key, value]) => 
  value === min ? key : null);
  const maxKey = Object.entries(obj).find(([key, value]) => 
  value === max ? key : null);
  return [Object.fromEntries([minKey]), Object.fromEntries([maxKey])];
} 

console.log(MinMaxFromObj(obj));
```

Comment: I need to define the object? I got the values from DB

Comment: if you receive data from the database as an object as described in the question. You can use this object, pass it to a function. But you should probably check the object already received from the database or not before doing so.

Comment: I get you, im now trying this and i will respond asap

Comment: Okay its working, but i cant figure out how can i make this to be like the object i added the log of

Comment: oh, i fixed function return, now it return array of objects.

Comment: or if you want not array of objects but just object you can write it like this: ```return {[minKey[0]]:min, [maxKey[0]]:max};```

Comment: You helped me alot in here

Comment: On stackoverflow you can say "thank you" by accepting the answer that helped you. )

Comment: Done bro, i forgot

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach which can help you to solve your problem:

```js
const minMaxEntry = (object) => {
  let minKey;
  let minValue = Infinity;

  let maxKey;
  let maxValue = -Infinity;

  for (const key in object) {
    if (object[key] < minValue) {
      minKey = key;
      minValue = object[key];
    }

    if (object[key] > maxValue) {
      maxKey = key;
      maxValue = object[key];
    }
  }

  const minEntry = { [minKey]: minValue };
  const maxEntry = { [maxKey]: maxValue };

  return [minEntry, maxEntry];
};

// --- //

const object = {
  "Learn JavaScript": 3,
  "Learn React": 2,
  "manicure": 1,
};

const [minEntry, maxEntry] = minMaxEntry(object);

console.log('Min Entry =>', minEntry);
// { "manicure": 1 }

console.log('Max Entry =>', maxEntry);
// { "Learn JavaScript": 3 }
```